# How do I answer UK visa question about other savings or income?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, pakistani-citizens, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a post-graduate student and I got a scholarship for a training course and to attend a conference in the UK. I totally depend on my father so how should I answer the question about whether I have any other income or savings?

Comment: Do you have any other income or savings?

Comment: No i don't have savings.as i mentioned i am dependent on my father he support me financially. can i use his bank account fund to answer this question?

Comment: You said that that is his income, not yours.

Comment: Doesn’t the application ask separately for who is going to support you and relevant details?

Comment: yes they are asking and i mention about orgination paying for my visit, but instead of this they are asking questions that do you have another income or savings?

Comment: Michael Hampton asked if you have any other income or savings. You answered "no". So how should you answer? "No", because that is the truth.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not clear from your question but assuming your father gives you an allowance / funds from time to time/regularly, I recommend that you state you have ‘Other regular income’, then select ‘Another Income’, then enter the total amount you receive from your father each year. You can explain the basis of your father’s support in the ‘Extra information’ section at the end of the application (and in your covering letter, if you’re submitting one) and you will need to substantiate this via your and your father’s bank statements and evidence of the source of his money eg pay slips.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience as I have got two Visa's from UK for the same purpose as yours you need tackle this question something like This!

**Do you have any other income or savings?**
Mention the account balance of YOUR bank account and support the claim with Bank Statement and Account Maintenance Certificate.

**Is anyone else paying for your trip?**
Yes, and write the detailed income of your father, also provide his source of income, tax returns and proof of relationships like FRC or Birth Certificate

**What you should write in your cover letter?**
The cover letter should be minimum A4 Size paper and should have followings things properly explained

Your personal information, education and job details if any!

Why this conference is important and what value it will add to your career?

Conference details and invitee details and how you got informed about this conference

Who is supporting your tour and why?

Write a paragraph telling the ECO that why you will return back to your home country (Familial Ties) like Full Time Education, Husband/Wife, Kids, Parents, Property, Investments and Job details.

Some of these points may not apply to you but please make sure you include everything in your application which convince the ECO that you will return back to your home country